# Помогите с регуляркой в Python плз, беда прям с ними

Tags: python, re

Строка может быть следующей:

```
Наименование (34)  (42)  (51)  (643)
```

Нужно вывести только последнее число `643` без скобок..

Comment: Это `\((\d{3})\)`?

Comment: или так `\d+(?=\)$)`

Comment: Добавляйте в вопрос вашу попытку решения.

Comment: не, че-то ни первый, ни второй не срабатывает..

Comment: @ВладСавельев попробуйте своё решение.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
regex = r"\d{3}"
test_str = ("Наименование (34)  (42)  (51)  (643)\n")
matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str)
for match in matches:
    print(match.group())

643
```